# Hive SQL - Conditional Count

Tags: hive, count, conditional-statements, hiveql

I got an issue in this conditional count and been stuck here for a day! Hope to find a solution here from you all.
So I have grade table which has three columns:
1. grand subject
2. subject (it's a breakdown of grand subject)
3. grade

```
    Grand_subject      Subject          Grade
-------------------------------------------------------
    Discrete Math   Discrete Math 1      A
                                         B
                                         B
                                         A
                                         A
                                         B
------------------------------------------------------
    Statistics       Statistics 1        A
                                         B
                                         B
                                         A
                                         A
-------------------------------------------------------
    Physics         Physics Basic        A
                                         A
                                         A
                                         B
                     ----------------------------------
                      Physics 1          B
                                         B
                                         B
                                         A
                     ----------------------------------
                      Physics 2          A
                                         A
                                         B
-------------------------------------------------------
    History           History 1          B
                                         A
                                         A
                                         B
                     ----------------------------------
                      History 2          A
                                         A
                                         B
                                         B
```

So, what I'm trying to do is, I'm going to count the percentage of A grade in the list for grand_subject and each subject {A grade percentage = how many A's divided by the number of A plus B grade (how many A's/(how many A's + how many B's)*100%}. There are two rules applied as following: 1). For these 2 grand sujects: **Discrete Math and Statistics, the grade calculation should be combined as** **Maths**; however, for **other grand subjects would be counted individually (Physics, History)**
2). For subjects column, the grade calculation should be done individually for each subjects.

The expected output is like below:

```
                                         A_Grade_Percentage
-----------------------------------------------------------------
    Maths (Discrete Math + Statistics)         54.50%
    Discrete Math 1                             50%
    Statistics 1                                60%
-----------------------------------------------------------------
    Physics                                   54.50%
    Physics Basic                               75%
    Physics 1                                   25%
    Physics 2                                 66.70%
-----------------------------------------------------------------
    History                                     50%
    History 1                                   50%
    History 2                                   50%
-----------------------------------------------------------------
    Geography                                   25%
```

So far I've tried this long code:

```
with on_grand_subject as(
select
case when grand_subject in ('Discrete Math', 'Statistics') then 'Maths'
     else grand_subject end as grand_subject,
count(case when grade = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as A_Grade,
100.0*count(case when grade = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) / 
   (count(case when grade = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) + count(case when grade = 'B' then 1 else 0 end)) 
   as A_Grade_percentage,
from
grade_table
where
 ...................
group by grand_subject in ('Discrete Math', 'Statistics') then 'Maths' else grand_subject end
order by grand_subject
limit 1000
),

on_subject as(
select
grand_subject,
subject,
count(case when grade = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as A_Grade,
100.0*count(case when grade = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) / 
   (count(case when grade = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) + count(case when grade = 'B' then 1 else 0 end)) 
   as A_Grade_percentage,
from
grade_table
where
 ...................
group by grand_subject, subject
order by subject
limit 1000
)

select
g.grand_subject, s.subject, g.A_Grade, g.A_Grade_percentage, s.A_Grade, g.A_Grade_percentage
from on_grand_subject g join on_subject s on g.grand_subject = s.grand_subject
```

But the output looks strange and not what it supposed to be. Is there any solutions for this? Thanks soo much!

Comment: This is wrong: `count(case when grade = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) ` because count will count 1 and 0 as well. it should be sum() instead of count. or remove `else 0` OR `else null`

Comment: You chances to get answer will be much better if you post text in convenient form, not pictures. Currently your dataset is impossible to reproduce other than using manual input.

Comment: @leftjoin Ah! Yes! I forgot to use the sum(), used to use count().. I'll try the sum() then, and by the way, I've edited question using the convenient form instead, thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Much better, but still some work required to get the normal dataset.

Comment: This may help: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Enhanced+Aggregation%2C+Cube%2C+Grouping+and+Rollup